# Retrieve column value in xpages view

Tags: xpages

I have a view control showing documents with an external url in document fieldA.
How can I write a onclick Event to open this URL?
Thanks for help.

Comment: You can always put HTML in that column.  Wrap your link in an anchor <a> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view column choose a content type of HTML.

[image]

In your view add a column that formats the link using the  tag.  Make this column hidden in the Notes client (if you use it there).  Then show this view column in your view control with the content type set to HTML.

Because you are using HTML, you don't need to have an onClick event per say, although the effect is the same.

Comment: The strange thing is that when I cklick the column I get a 404 not found and if I copy/paste the url into the browser it works as expected.

Comment: Check your HTML source code using 'Inspect Element' in your browser.  Also check what URL gives you the 404, you should have a clue there what is wrong.

Comment: @GeraldClerc I edited my answer when I thought of a better way to build the HTML.